# Meaning of extended audiotape.

Tags: vocabulary

What does "**extended audiotape**" means? I found the meaning for "extended" and found out that it means "prolonged". Then does "**extended audiotape**" mean a tape that plays for long time?

Comment: What is the context? Please give more information.

Comment: In your *precise* context the intended meaning is probably a slightly metaphoric extension of the literal sense of *extended*. Most likely the reference is to an audiotape recording of some "base" material (perhaps a recording of a band playing a gig) that has been "extended" with additional material (perhaps interviews with the band members included before or after the main content, or "critques" of each song interspersed into the program).

Comment: I doubt it mean "**enlarged**", your guess is correct "**lasting longer than is usual or expected; prolonged.**"

Comment: I doubt many people still use audio compact cassettes, but originally there were technical quality implications to packing them with longer, thinner tape. The standard C90 cassette was 90 minutes, but you could get C120 and above, which some people would have called "extended play" cassettes.

Comment: Often time-lengthened tapes (audio and video) were called "extended-play tapes". But additional context or an example product is needed to answer the question. If I recall there were such things like "extended frequency response" tapes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This is the Amazon link](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B014GJBP54) for the extended version of the *Hobbit* movies. They were called extended because they had additional scenes than the movies that were released in theaters.

Although it would be easier with context, from your question, I am assuming that the audiotape was released, and then released as an extended audiotape, which was longer than the original.